# Creating JSON (with sub-arrays) from Powershell hash table

Tags: json, powershell

I have a list of property names and values that looks like this:

```
[string[]]$PropertyNames = 'name', 'priority', 'levelStr', 'escalatingChainId', 'supressAlertClear', 'deviceGroups'
[string[]]$PropertyValues = 'Test', '19665999', 'Warn', '3', 'false', 'TestGroup,TestGroup2'
```

I am trying to turn it into JSON where whatever value is associated with deviceGroups, should be considered an array;

```
Foreach ($property in $PropertyNames) {
    Switch ($property) {
        {$_ -in ("deviceGroups", "devices")} {
            $propertyData.Add($_, @($($PropertyValues[$index])))

            $index++
        }
        default {
            $propertyData.Add($_, $($PropertyValues[$index]))

            $index++
        }
    }
}
```

This generates JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "name":  "Test",
    "priority":  "19665999",
    "levelStr":  "Warn",
    "escalatingChainId":  3
    "supressAlertClear": "false"
    "deviceGroups":  [
                    "TestGroup, TestGroup2"
                    ],
    ]
}
```

That's no good, because TestGroup and TestGroup2 should be on separate lines (since that is supposed to be a JSON array).
How do I turn these strings into valid JSON (where deviceGroups key/value (which could be comma-separated) must be an array)?

Comment: Is deviceGroups an array? When I try this it works fine.

Comment: I edited the original post to better indicate what I'm starting with.

Comment: I edited the original post again. I'm not getting the deviceGroups on separate lines. They are a single string within the deviceGroups array, which is in correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you forgot to split the string:

```
Foreach ($property in $PropertyNames) {
    Switch ($property) {
        {$_ -in ("deviceGroups", "devices")} {
            $propertyData.Add($_, @($PropertyValues[$index] -split ','))

            $index++
        }
        default {
            $propertyData.Add($_, $($PropertyValues[$index]))

            $index++
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And `($PropertyValues[$index] -split ',').Trim()` if you want to attempt to handle such cases.

Comment: Yup, I ended up with the same. ```$propertyData.Add($_, @(($($PropertyValues[$index]).Split(","))).Trim())```. Thanks.